# read line from especific line from file in directory c#

Tags: c#, .net

this code works fine but my problem is that i need to read the files that contains ESSD and if this file contains a name in certain line, add it to my listbox1, and if it doesnt contain the name in that line, dont add it to the listbox1.

Thanks.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult result = this.openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string[] Nomarchivo = this.openFileDialog1.FileNames;
            string NomDirec = Path.GetDirectoryName(Nomarchivo[0]);
            for (int a = 0; a <= Nomarchivo.Length - 1; a++)
            {
                string NomDirGral = Nomarchivo[a].Remove(Nomarchivo[a].Length - 7, 7);
                string NomGral = NomDirGral.Replace(NomDirec, " ");
                NomGral = NomGral.Remove(0, 2);
                foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(NomDirec, NomGral + "*"))
                    this.listBox1.Items.Add(f);
                foreach (string h in Directory.GetFiles(NomDirec, "resume*"))
                    this.listBox1.Items.Add(h);
                foreach (string t in Directory.GetFiles(NomDirec, "ESSD1*"))
                    this.listBox1.Items.Add(t);
            }
            string[] list1 = new string[listBox1.Items.Count];
            for (int b = 0; b <= listBox1.Items.Count - 1; b++)
            {
                list1[b] = listBox1.Items[b].ToString();
            }
            string[] list2 = list1.Distinct().ToArray();
            foreach (string g in list2)
                this.listBox2.Items.Add(g);

            Class1 arr1 = new Class1();
            arr1.array(listBox2);
        }
        else { Close(); }
    }
```

Comment: And? What's the problem? You have neglected to ask a question or explain the issue.

Comment: Well the problem is that i want to access the ESSD file and the read line 6, if this line contains a name that is stored in the Resume file, send the ESSD file to listbox1, and if not, doesnt add ESSD to my listbox1

Comment: Great. And what is stopping you from doing that? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.NET 4 offers a nice function called File.ReadLines(fileName)

With this function, your above code can be modified as:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    DialogResult result = this.openFileDialog1.ShowDialog(); 
    if (result == DialogResult.OK) 
    { 
        string[] Nomarchivo = this.openFileDialog1.FileNames; 
        string NomDirec = Path.GetDirectoryName(Nomarchivo[0]); 
        for (int a = 0; a <= Nomarchivo.Length - 1; a++) 
        { 

            //the name we are looking for.
            List<string> namesWeAreLookingFor = new List<string>();

            string NomDirGral = Nomarchivo[a].Remove(Nomarchivo[a].Length - 7, 7); 
            string NomGral = NomDirGral.Replace(NomDirec, " "); 
            NomGral = NomGral.Remove(0, 2); 
            foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(NomDirec, NomGral + "*")) 
                this.listBox1.Items.Add(f); 
            foreach (string h in Directory.GetFiles(NomDirec, "resume*")) 
            {
                this.listBox1.Items.Add(h); 

                var nameLines = File.ReadLines(NomDirec + @"\" + h);
                foreach (var item in nameLines)
                {
                    //do whatever you need to get a name in this file here
                    //...

                    //Assuming there is one name per line, add the name to the list
                    namesWeAreLookingFor.Add(item);
                }
            }
            foreach (string t in Directory.GetFiles(NomDirec, "ESSD1*")) 
            {
                this.listBox1.Items.Add(t); 
                //try to access the file so we can read line 6 using new .NET 4 method 
                var lines = File.ReadLines(NomDirec + @"\" + t);

                //see if we even have 6 lines
                if (lines.Count() < 6)
                    continue;

                String line6 = lines.ElementAt(5);

                //loop through the names we pulled
                foreach (var item in namesWeAreLookingFor)
                {
                    //see if line 6  containes that name.
                    if (line6.Contains(item))
                    {
                        //if it exists, then add it to the list and exit the loop.
                        this.listBox1.Items.Add(t);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        } 
        string[] list1 = new string[listBox1.Items.Count]; 
        for (int b = 0; b <= listBox1.Items.Count - 1; b++) 
        { 
            list1[b] = listBox1.Items[b].ToString(); 
        } 
        string[] list2 = list1.Distinct().ToArray(); 
        foreach (string g in list2) 
            this.listBox2.Items.Add(g); 

        Class1 arr1 = new Class1(); 
        arr1.array(listBox2); 
    } 
    else { Close(); }
```

Comment: @Carl - I did understand that you want to pull the names to search from from the Resume files, right?  (as indicated by your comment to Oded)

Comment: Hi saml, in the weekend I finally figured out how to recover the name from the ESSD file, I discovered that line 6 only contain one part of the name I had to compare, the other parts where in line 7 and 8, but only a concatenation of strings was  needed to fix this, now I need to compare the new string of my full name to the full names that are shown in my resume files, and if it appear on the resume file then I can add it to my listbox, reading the code that you write I only have one question, what are you telling exactly in the File.Readlines(Nomarchivo+@"\"+h)??? ,

Comment: I guess what I need to do is add the lines of my Resume file to a List, then compare my Full name string to this lines and if it match add the ESSD file to my listbox, what do you think? I really apreciate your help THANKS!

Comment: Oops that was a mistake (See edited post).  I meant to write NomDirec + @"\" + h.  This will get you the directory path to the file you want.

Yeah that is the general idea of what you need to do.  I gave a very basic way to do this.  You can make it as elegant / effecient as you need it to be, but now you have a general idea of what you want to do.

Comment: Don't forget to accept this as the answer if you used it.

Comment: the contain method doesnt work because the lines of the list not only have name, it also have other data like age, weight, height and adress, how can I only read the first part, the name is the only thing that i need right now, how can i use a custom delimiter, that only read before  ":"?

Comment: Hi Carl,  my first answer will always be to use RegEx to find what you are looking for when working with strings.  However, read up on the String class on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string_methods(v=vs.71).aspx).  You just might find a simple function that does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here's two ways:

```
public static string ReadSpecificLine1( string path , int lineNumber )
{
  int cnt = 0 ;
  string desiredLine = File.ReadAllLines( path ).FirstOrDefault( x => (++cnt == lineNumber) ) ;
  return desiredLine ;
}

public static string ReadSpecificLine2( string path , int lineNumber )
{
  string desiredLine = null ;
  using ( FileStream   stream = new FileStream( path , FileMode.Open , FileAccess.Read , FileShare.Read ) )
  using ( StreamReader reader = new StreamReader( stream ) )
  {
    int    i           = 0    ;
    string line        = null ;
    while ( null != (line=reader.ReadLine()) && ++i < lineNumber )
    {
    }
    if ( i == lineNumber && line != null )
    {
       desiredLine = line ;
    }
    return desiredLine ;
  }
}
```

If you know for certain that your file

- Contains only characters that comprise a single, fixed-size Unicode code unit in the file's unicode encoding scheme, **and**
- has fixed length lines (records)

Then you can `seek()` directly to the line in question, as in this example using UTF-16 encoding, thus saving extraneous I/O operations:

```
public static string ReadSpecificLineFromUTF16EncodedFile( string path , int lineNumber )
{
  string    desiredLine                    = null ;

  using ( FileStream   stream = new FileStream( path , FileMode.Open , FileAccess.Read , FileShare.Read ) )
  using ( StreamReader reader = new StreamReader( stream , Encoding.Unicode ) )
  {
    Encoding  UTF_16                         = Encoding.Unicode ;
    const int RECORD_LENGTH_IN_CHARS         = 80 ;
    const int FIXED_CODE_UNIT_SIZE_IN_OCTETS = sizeof(char) ; // size of a UTF-16 code unit (char) in octets
    const int RECORD_LENGTH_IN_OCTETS        = RECORD_LENGTH_IN_CHARS * FIXED_CODE_UNIT_SIZE_IN_OCTETS ;

    long offset = (lineNumber-1)*RECORD_LENGTH_IN_OCTETS ;

    if ( offset <  0 ) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("lineNumber") ;
    if ( offset <= stream.Length )
    {
      stream.Seek( offset , SeekOrigin.Begin ) ;
      desiredLine = reader.ReadLine() ;
    }
  }
  return desiredLine ;
}
```

Note that this will **only** work if the above two conditions are true.

Answer (score 0):

> Well the problem is that i want to access the ESSD file and the read
>   line 6, if this line contains a name that is stored in the Resume
>   file, send the ESSD file to listbox1, and if not, doesnt add ESSD to
>   my listbox1

So:

1. Read/Parse the resume file
2. Sort the Resume list.
3. Create a list of all the ESSD files
4. Iterate through said list reading "Line 6" from each file
5. search resume file for name in "Line 6"
6. Add if found

Try to add that into your above code and see what happens. See how it goes and revise your question maybe.

Comment: HI SH-, the part of searching in the resume file is what bothers me, I know how to get my name of my ESSD file, but how can i compare it to names in the resume file? THANKS!